# Least common multiple of many numbers

Tags: random-numbers

I need to make visualization like this: [image]

In this case we have 3 numbers I need to make it with 2 or 3.
It will be very good if it looks like this - here we have denominating only 1 number.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{denom}{%
   \setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}%
   \array[t]{@{}r|r@{}}}{\endarray}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{denom} 
12 & 2\\
6 & 2\\
3 & 3\\
1&
\end{denom}\quad 
\begin{denom}
26 & 2\\
13 & 13\\
1&
\end{denom}\quad
\begin{denom}
256 & 2\\
128 & 2\\
64 & 2\\
32 & 2\\
16 & 2\\
8 & 2\\
4 & 2\\
2 & 2\\
1 &
\end{denom}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{denom}[1]
 {\array[t]{@{}*{#1}{r}|r@{}}}
 {\endarray}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{denom}{3}
12 & 26 & 256 & 2 \\
 6 & 13 & 128 & 2 \\
 3 & 13 &  64 & 2 \\
 3 & 13 &  32 & 2 \\
 3 & 13 &  16 & 2 \\
 3 & 13 &   8 & 2 \\
 3 & 13 &   4 & 2 \\
 3 & 13 &   2 & 2 \\
 3 & 13 &   1 & 3 \\
 1 & 13 &     & 13 \\
   &  1 &     &
\end{denom}
\qquad
\begin{denom}{2}
28 & 98 & 2 \\
14 & 49 & 2 \\
 7 & 49 & 7 \\
 1 &  7 & 7 \\
   &  1 & 
\end{denom}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]